# Android KitKat and Widevine DRM

Tags: android, android-4.2-jelly-bean, android-4.4-kitkat, drm, widevine

My application was loading HLS videos and now I need to add Widevinew DRM support.

And I am experiencing strange problems with Widevine DRM on Android devices with OS higher then 4.2
It is working on 4.0.3 and 4.1.1 devices perfectly (rights are downloaded, video is played) but when I try same code on devices with OS higher then 4.2 (I have Galaxy Note 2 OS 4.3, Nexus 4 OS 4.4.4, Galaxy Note 10 2014 Edition OS 4.3, Galaxy Tab 3 OS 4.3, Nexus 7 OS 4.4.2) it fails after trying to play video, MediaPlayer just throws an error (1, -1)

Does anyone faced same issue? I was thinking newer version has less problems then previous ones, but it is not always true, unfortunately.

Best regards, Artem

Comment: Asked Google people about this issue and they said DRM Widevine is not supported since OS 4.3
So I should find some 3rd party frameworks for this now

Comment: You can try to replace "http" with "widevine" protocol in your video url. It helped in my case.

Comment: it is already there...